# $V$, $U$ vector spaces, $V$ isomorphic to $U$. Then $\mathrm{dim} \,V = \mathrm{dim}\, U$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi: I say: Let $B_1$ and $B_2$ be bases of $V$ and $U$ respectively. And let $T$ be a nonsingular linear transformation from $V$ to $U$. Assume $\dim V=m$ and $\dim U=n$ and $m > n$. $T$ will send $B_1$ into a basis $C$ of $U$. And so there will be two bases for $U$: $B_2$ and $C$.

And here I expect a contradiction will appear. For instance the elements of $C$ being linearly dependent. Or $B_2$ not generating $U$. But I cannot prove neither one thing nor the other.

Comment: In a vector space of dimension $k$, every subset with more than $k$ vectors is linearly dependent.

Comment: Yes. Say dim V = n with $B$={$v_1,...,v_n}$ a basis. If $u_1,...,u_{n+1}$ belong to V, then I can write $u_{n+1}$ as a linear combination of the $v_i$ and therefor get a linear combination of ... hummm. I don't get it.

Comment: As you said, T will send $B_1$ to a basis $C$ of $U$, but with $m$ elements, and $m>n$, so $C$ is linearly dependent. This is a contradiction because the elements of a basis are linearly independent by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to do by contradiction. If $\mathcal{B}_1$ is a basis for $V$, then the image of $\mathcal{B}_1$ under $T$ is a set of $m$ linearly independent vectors. This must mean that $n \geq m$. Do the same for $\mathcal{B}_2$, and we have $m \geq n$. Combining both yields equality.

Comment: Ah! I apply $T^{-1}$ to B2 and I get n vectors which are linearly independent in B1. So m >= n.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I have just clicked on "This answer is useful".

Answer (score 0):

The number of vectors in a basis is always the same, for a given vector space.   And an isomorphism takes a basis to a basis.

(I want to say) both of these facts are relatively straightforward to prove.

*Dimension Theory* by Witold Hurewicz and Henry Wallman is a book I will refer you to for (probably) deeper thoughts on the subject.   Though I'm not sure how much attention there is to vector spaces,  as such (if any).